# angular 2 get FormControl in template as local variable

Tags: angular, form-control

I use in angular 2 model driven forms,when the user leaves the input element i want update data in server immediately (autosave).

So, my solution is use the `(blur)` event and pass the form control to a function, then check the `dirty` property if is true, then update the server.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

```html
 <input type="text"
 formControlName="firstName"
 [(ngModel)]="contact.firstName"
 #ctrl=[currentFormControl]
 (blur)="onBlur(ctrl)"
                    />
```

frm.component.ts:

```js
  onBlur(formControl: FormControl){

      if(formControl.dirty){
          //update server
          formControl.reset();
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very simple

```
<form *ngIf="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="contactForm">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input type="text"
                   formControlName="firstName"
                   [(ngModel)]="contact.firstName"
                   (blur)="onBlur(contactForm.controls['firstName'])"
            />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by  user lost control, but there is functionality built into angular router called CanDeactivate which allows you to stop navigation on any condition or to perform an action like saving data.

Refer sample application here - [angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html](http://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html)

Comment: i mean "Leaving control" (like "after update" control in ms access) 
sorry for my bad english